# Notation - questions like - How much more probable is getting 5 heads and 5 tails than 9 heads and 1 tail?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, notation, combinations

**Original Question: A well-balanced coin is flipped 10 times.**
**How much more likely is it to get 5Heads & 5Tails vs 9Heads & 1Tail?**

### *The math operations aren't confusing for me. I just have problems thinking through the problems, which is more a notation-related problem, understanding what the math labels.*

A fair coin has an equal chance of hitting heads || tails. 
ie. 50% likelihood of anything.

In general for problems like this:

**the formula** = *multiplicity of event* **x** *probability associated with sub-events*.

In this case, multiplicity is determined by the combination formula, because the desired outcome is content specific, not priority specific.

Ω = multiplicity

Ω_5H = C(10,5)=252

Ω_9H = C(10,9)=C(10,1)=10

(1/2)^10 <-- associated with flipping coin 10 times.

**What specifically does the (1/2)^10 describe in a generic sense?**

- The probability of all subevents?
- What do you call the situation of flipping the coin 10 times?

**in assessing the likelihood ratio**: it's the same if you just consider the multiplicities.

Comment: $(1/2)^{10}$ is the probability of obtaining a single ordered string of $10$ heads or tails.

Comment: The more number of time you flip the coin, the probability of most likely outcome increases. So ${(1/2)}^{10}$ in general sense, is the factor leading towards equilibrium

Comment: @user168282 - multiplying a decimal by another decimal always leads to a smaller value. The difference between 9H and 5H, is that 5H has a higher multiplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems like these are group events. This is why you need to consider multiplicities and why a probability factor is scaled.**

*Finding the likelihood of getting 5Heads & 5Tails || 9Heads & 1Tail ...
is actually a problem of finding the probability for a set of independent events.*

In this description getting heads on one flip assumes that getting heads on the next flip is also equally random.

**Thus going back to the formula:**

the probability of the group event || set of independent events is defined as thus

Pgroup= Ωgroup * (probability of individual event)^number of component events.

Ωgroup= the number of multiple ways you can acquire the group arrangement

probability of individual event = defined by some process described in the problem

**Going back to the example problem:**

- P_specific_combination= Ωcombination x (probability of getting head
  on 1 flip)^#flips
- P_5H,5T = C(10,5) x (1/2)^10
- (1/2)^10 describes the getting heads on each flip.

Answer (score 2):

The "sub-events" you are talking about are usually called *outcomes*. These are individual *elements* of the sample space (as opposed to *events*, which are *subsets* of the sample space).

So the sample space of flipping a coin $10$ times is the set of all ordered strings of $H,T$ of length $10$:
$$S=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{10}) : x_i = H \text{ or T}, 1 \leq i \leq 10\}.$$
An outcome of this sample space is an individual string, e.g., $(H,T,H,H,T,T,T,H,H,T)$. Each outcome in this sample space is associated with a probability, which is $(1/2)^{10}$ (i.e., all outcomes are equally likely).

An event in this sample space could be something like the event of getting $9$ heads and $1$ tail. This event is a set consisting of $10$ different outcomes:
$$\{(H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,T), (H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,T,H), \dots\}.$$
The probability of an event is the sum of the probabilities of all outcomes in the event. Since all outcomes are equally likely with probability $(1/2)^{10}$, this works out to $(\#\text{outcomes in the event} ) \times(1/2)^{10}$.

The situation of flipping the coin $10$ times could be called different things depending on the context. For instance, the general setup could be called an "experiment" ("consider the experiment of flipping a fair coin ten times..."). An particular instance of this experiment would be called an *outcome* as I explained above.